# What is the true nature of the object returned by the Arrays.asList() method?

Tags: java

[Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) on method `asList()` from `Arrays` class, has `List<T>` as a return type. Since you can *not* instantiate an interface in Java, what is the true "nature" of that object?

Consider the following example:

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Following this example, `list` is of `List<Integer>` type. But, what is its inherent type?

---

If it's not clear what I mean by true nature of an object or its inherent type, `List randomObject = new ArrayList();`, true nature of `randomObject` would be `ArrayList`, and not `List`.

Comment: You may be interested in result of `list.getClass()`.

Comment: Or use a debugger, and inspect `list` to determine it's type.

Comment: Either way, the JavaDoc tells you everything you need to know - it is fixed-size, serializable and random-access and backed by the array. The rest are implementation details and may vary from implementation to implementation.

Comment: if you really need to know, the type of returned instance - with actual Java (OpenJDK 20) - is `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` - a nested class of `Arrays`, (unfortunately also) called `ArrayList` (not same as `java.util.ArrayList`) || Since that is not mentioned in the specification (aka javadoc,) this can be changed at any time, even be different in the same execution of the JVM (e.g. result of `List.of()` which depends on number of arguments AFAIK)

Comment: The actual class is an implementation detail, and you should not worry about that.